# Как преобразовать словарь в строку Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Дано список словарей:

```
dictionary = [{'персона': 'человек',
              'марафон': 'гонка бегунов длиной около 26 миль',
              'противостоять': 'оставаться сильным, несмотря на давление',
              'бежать': 'двигаться со скоростью'}]
```

Как преобразовать их в строку и отформатировать чтобы выводились примерно так:
*Персона: человек;
Марафон: гонка бегунов;
Противостоять: оставаться сильным.*

Comment: покажите код, который вы уже написали, и расскажите, какие там проблемы

Comment: Код весь скинуть не могу, проблема в том, что есть список словарей, и их надо записать в текстовый файл, а для этого надо преобразовать в строку.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
dictionary = [{'персона': 'человек',
              'марафон': 'гонка бегунов длиной около 26 миль',
              'противостоять': 'оставаться сильным, несмотря на давление',
              'бежать': 'двигаться со скоростью'}]


result = '; '.join([f'{key.capitalize()}: {value}' for key, value in dictionary[0].items()])

print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Как то так можно, только я убрал список, оставил только словарь.

```
dictionary = {'персона': 'человек',
              'марафон': 'гонка бегунов длиной около 26 миль',
              'противостоять': 'оставаться сильным, несмотря на давление',
              'бежать': 'двигаться со скоростью'}
strings = []
for key,item in dictionary.items():
    strings.append("{}: {}".format(key.capitalize(), item))
result = "; ".join(strings)
print(result)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
def info_kwargs1(**kwargs):
    [print(f'{k} = {v}') for k, v in sorted(kwargs.items())]
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: вводишь свой словарь и он сортируется в алфавитном порядке и выводиться строкой

Comment: Это пример того, как не нужно использовать списковые выражения.